# Use composition in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, erb, forms

I don't know which is the best or right way to make something, so I'm looking for suggestions.

**Stage**:
I am using Rails 3 to make some web app.
Imaging two models: `Canvas` and `Zone`.
A `canvas` object intents to be a square in which there will be four `zone`'s (north, south, east and west).
Each `zone` has these attributes: `text:string` and `rgb_color:string`.
I want to render a HTML form in which user must capture a Canvas registry, in other words, in this form will have four groups of zones fields.

**Problem**:
How can I capture all of them in one HTML form?

If I would have only one zone I can do something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@zone) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :text %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :text %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :rgb_color %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :rgb_color %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But how should I do it with four zones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) and [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for):

Model:

```
class Canvas < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :zones
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :zones
end
```

Controller:

```
class CanvasesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @canvas = Canvas.new
    4.times { @canvas.zones.build }
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for(@canvas) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :zones do |zone| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= zone.label :text %><br />
      <%= zone.text_field :text %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= zone.label :rgb_color %><br />
      <%= zone.text_field :rgb_color %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

For more details and explanation have a look at this:

- [Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
- [Nested Model Form Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

Comment: One more question...
Is there a way to make a transaction to guarantee save all models? There must be saved/updated Canvas and their four zones, if one of them fail, all must be rolled back.

Comment: @NeoRiddle, glad to hear it works. As for the validation of your nested attributes, not sure. You can use `reject_if` with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595969/validate-number-of-nested-attributes) is relevant. If you cannot figure it out, just open a new question. Good luck.