# Validate number of attributes with date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, date, nested-attributes

I'm doing something like the following: [Validate number of nested attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595969/validate-number-of-nested-attributes).
I'm checking for existence of at least one nested attribute.

This was working fine when I was using a text input for the date but I've changed it to use a date_select instead and now the same validation code shows an error saying that not enough have been chosen.

When it fails validation and reloads the form it also doesn't "build" an instance of the nested attribute either so it just shows my "[+]" link

Anybody got any ideas?

Failing everything I'll just have to put the text field back (probably using type=date).

Col

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just put the text field back.